# Live Stream using .m3u8 and .ts files with iPhone as server

Tags: ios, objective-c, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I am trying to accomplish a task to live stream from iPhone camera. I have done some research and found that i can use `.m3u8` files for streaming live video with should contain .`ts(Mpeg-2)` files .

Now the file which i have on my iPhone is `.mp4` file and it does not work with .m3u8, so i figured out i will have to convert `.mp4` to `.ts` for that , but i have not succeeded in doing so.

I found that it is possible to convert video [ffmpeg lib](https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script) as mentioned in [this article here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2003105). I have successfully imported `ffmpeg` library but not able figure out how can i use it to convert a video as i am using this for first time.

One another thing [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/Introduction/Introduction.html) says

> There are a number of hardware and software encoders that can create
>   MPEG-2 transport streams carrying MPEG-4 video and AAC audio in real
>   time.

What is being said here? is there any other way i can use .mp4 files for live streaming without converting them from iOS?

Let me know if i am not clear, i can provide more information .Any suggestion is appreciated. I would like to know am i on a right path here?

**EDIT**

I am adding more info to my question, so basically what i am asking is , we can convert .mp4 video to .ts using following command

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -acodec libfaac -vcodec libx264 -an -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list test.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -flags -global_header stream%05d.ts
```

How can i use ffmpeg library to do what this command does in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at ffmpeg.c to see what the ffmpeg uses from the ffmpeg libraries. It's a pretty complicated file, however. You may want to rename main() and compile it to an object, then you could call the new ffmpeg_main() function from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Apple device work on HLS only and you need to convert the media files from mp4 to ts along with the metadata file as m3u8. You can use the streamers like gstreamer etc to stream you mp4 to HLS format or the other way is to trans-code on fly which is very slow.